# How can I listen to my guitar in realtime via the microphone input?

Tags: sound

I can playback my guitar through the mic in once I've recorded something, but I can't hear the guitar in real-time as I could in Windows?

Comment: Try rakarrack for some cool effects

Answer (score 1):

give alsamixer command in terminal, move with arrow to the microphone and press M to unmute it.

Comment: You saved my life.